# How to implement Push Notifications in Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying from more than a day to implement a simple PUSH notification using gcm, but unable to implement it.

When ever I am adding this permission

```
<permission android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

I get this error message while debugging via mobile device

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Android.Test
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

Can somebody suggest me what I am doing. for further help I am putting my whole manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="Android.Test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

    <permission android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <uses-permission android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />



    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="Android.Test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Edit 1:
This is how I am trying to send the message from C# to my android device.....I found this code from the blog.

```
private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
        {

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

            //
            //  MESSAGE CONTENT
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            //
            //  CREATE REQUEST
            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            Request.Method = "POST";
            Request.KeepAlive = false;
            Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
            Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
            Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            //
            //  SEND MESSAGE
            try
            {
                WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
                HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
                if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
                {
                    var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";

                }
                else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
                }

                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                Reader.Close();

                return responseLine;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return "error";
        }
```

This is what I am getting in the responseLine code

```
{"multicast_id":7357801824672,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/19226-android-push-notification-gcm-framework-tutorial.html

Comment: Should be your package name fault. Don't use `capital` in your package name. Try to rename it to `com.android.test` and see if you can install or not

Comment: Aprian, I followed your suggestion and it worked now I am able to compile and run the app on the phone, but I am unable to receive a message on the phone. I am pushing my messages from c# .net but they are not reaching to phone any suggestions...please...

Comment: If the problem, **as initially posed**, is solved, accept the answer and post a new question. This one is overloaded with pasted code as it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579202/issue-with-gcm-manifest-malformed-as-a-result-of-capital-letter-in-package-name

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Main activity. -->
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="Android.Test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: now i am able to compile but while execution I got this error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

Comment: <permission
        android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

Comment: no luck, "same error pkg: /data/local/tmp/Android.Test
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]"

Comment: i thinks the problem is not in manifest file because i done same one last 2days back its working fine to me.check once the tutorial of GCM

Comment: raju, i am able to compile and execute the app by following Aprian's suggestion, but now I am unable to receive the message, See Edit 1 for info.

Answer (score 0):

Your response code contains the answer, you are passing invalid registration_ids

```
    "results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]
```

Sample php code:

```
    $postdata = array(
        'registration_ids' => array('your_device_registration_key'),
        'data' => 'message'
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . YOUR_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
```