# Issue with GCM. Manifest malformed as a result of capital letter in package name 

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem when I try to add GCM in my application, when the package name starts with capital letter.

The problem is in the code:

```
<permission android:name="Myapplication.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

When you try to install it in the emulator the output is:

```
install_parse_failed_manifest_malformed
```

If you are starting a new application you can solve it changing the package name from *"Myapplication.com"* to *"myapplication.com"* (little letters), but if you're updating an already existing application you cannot do that, because Google Play does not admit the change of the package name when updating.